# How to read embed thumbnail from jpeg images?

Tags: c++, jpeg, thumbnails, exif

I am writing a thumbnail viewer in c++.

I first make use of EXIF information to retrive an image's thumbnail, but the thumbnail in the EXIF is bad, with black bands. So I want to get the jpeg's embedded thumbnail, how can I do this?

Another question:
does jpeg's embeded thumbnail equal to EXIF thumbnial?

Comment: You're not making a lot of sense.  The only thumbnail in a JFIF file is the EXIF thumbnail.  JFIF only allows for storing a single image in a file and the thumbnail is "hidden" in the EXIF header.  What do you mean by "embedded" thumbnail?  As mentioned below, you can create a fast thumbnail from the DC values of each MCU that will be 1/64th the size of the original image.  Not sure what you mean by "corrupt" thumbnail image.  There are black bars added on some cameras because the image is not the same aspect ratio as the standard 160x120 thumbnai image.

Comment: many thanks BitBank! I see, At first I was puzzled about the black bars, do you know how to remove the black bars?

Comment: The black bars are part of the image.  In order to remove them you'll have to crop the image based on the original image size. e.g. if the original image is 1600x1200, there won't be any black bars because the 160x120 thumbnail is the same ratio.  If the image is 3888x2592, then the thumbnail will be 160x106.

Answer (score 7):

If the EXIF thumbnail is bad, you can generate your own from the JPEG itself, without needing to completely decode the JPEG.

Look for the source code for **EPEG**. It's part of the Enlightenment project on SourceForge, and was part of the old EFL a year ago. You can still dig it up from some old SVN commits or from a source tarball that might be floating around.

Basically, what EPEG does, is it collects the DCT coefficients from the image, and performs a rescaling operation on them. The DCT coefficient is normally used as the base coefficient for an 8x8 block of pixels. You can treat it as *one* pixel. As a result, you have a (computationally free) thumbnail exactly 1/8th the size of the original image. Rescale it as you would any image data to the desired dimensions.

Comment: Many thanks, Is there any EPEG windows lib? How can I compile it under windows ?

Comment: It was written for the Enlightenment project, so the source code is originally very *nix-centric, but it was still written in a very OS-agnostic style. It should compile fine on Windows, straight out of the SVN checkout. There's no precompiled Windows lib to my knowledge. I believe there are makefiles already included for Windows.

Comment: There's a link to some snapshots in the comments in my related answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316170/having-an-image-file-buffer-in-memory-what-is-the-fastest-way-to-create-its-thum

Answer (score 2):

In the majority of cases where people talk about JPEG files having thumbnails, they mean the file is JPEG-EXIF and the EXIF data contains a thumbnail image.

However, it is true to say that [JFIF 1.02](http://www.jpeg.org/public/jfif.pdf) supports a thumbnail image. The thumbnail may be stored in the JFIF APP0 marker or an official JFXX APP0 extension marker; the thumbnail may be uncompressed RGB, JPEG or palletted. See
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#JFIF_segment_format for details.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and recommended ways are libraries.

For example, [www.exiv2.org](http://www.exiv2.org) can provide you with the library for embedded thumbnail and EXIF info extraction. There is a lot of alternatives, but I think this one is a good solution.

Answer (score -1):

www.exiv2.org in my eyes is a bad solution. There are just too many deps to other projects. Expat and zlib for instance. If you want to come up with a lightweight solution that you can support on your own, I would recommend to write your own EXIF decoder.